# How to put an output value to a variable in R?

Tags: r

I am studying programming in R. My job is to find an alpha value of Cronbach's alpha test in statistics. I learned that I can do it by the following code:

```
library(psych)
MyData <- read.csv(file="C://path//Aineisto.csv", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
alpha(MyData)
```

Now the output starts like this:

```
Reliability analysis   
Call: alpha(x = MyData)

  raw_alpha std.alpha G6(smc) average_r S/N    ase mean   sd
      0.94      0.94    0.96      0.36  15 0.0052  3.5 0.63
```

How can I save that raw_alpha value to a new variable, say temp, to use that in further analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` can always help show you the structure of the object. Using the example of the documentation `?alpha`:

```
set.seed(42) #keep the same starting values
#four congeneric measures
r4 <- sim.congeneric()
relan <- alpha(r4)
#check str(relan) to see the structure

> relan$total$raw_alpha
[1] 0.7420547
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = mtcars
dt <- alpha(data)

dt$total$raw_alpha
[1] 0.4091521

dt$alpha.drop$raw_alpha
 [1]  0.45327946  0.40041073 -0.12772978 -0.08239659  0.41597064  0.40682625  0.42117578  0.41623570  0.41517990
[10]  0.41569866  0.40641280
```